# i got error ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00979

I got Error `ORA-00979` with the following query:

```
SELECT d.department_name "department name",
       e.job_id "job title",
       SUM(e.salary) "monthly cost", 
       GROUPING(d.department_id) "Department ID Used",
       GROUPING(e.job_id) "Job ID Used"
FROM   employees e
       JOIN departments d
       ON e.department_id=d.department_id
GROUP BY cube(d.department_name, e.job_id)
ORDER BY d.department_name, e.job_id
```

Is any wrong with query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `GROUPING(d.department_id)` but `department_id` is not in the `GROUP BY` clause.

You could add it to the `GROUP BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT d.department_name "department name",
       e.job_id "job title",
       SUM(e.salary) "monthly cost",
       GROUPING(d.department_id) "Department ID Used",
       GROUPING(e.job_id) "Job ID Used"
FROM   employees e
       JOIN departments d
       ON e.department_id=d.department_id
GROUP BY cube(d.department_name, d.department_id, e.job_id)
ORDER BY d.department_name, e.job_id
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=da463f20d2e058c9d497db76ce18d733)*

Comment: Thanks for your help, now i can run the query now